# How to measure the difference in memory usage between C# and Java?

Tags: java, c#, memory, memory-management

I'd like to measure the difference in memory usage for an application in C# and Java. My theory is that, since the languages are quite similar, the memory usage between C# and Java, or perhaps between the CLR and the JVM, are quit similar.

However, I'd like to test this, and hopefully publish an article on it. What is a way to test memory between these 2 environments, and what are the things I have to take into account while measuring them? (For example, does the VM have a big impact on the memory usage? What technique should I use for measuring memory? And should I write a simple program without Frameworks, or include a Web Framework like Spring?)

So, just to clear on this: I'm not looking for opinions, but I'm looking for a method and the correct environment on how to create a test which objectively compares the two platforms.

Comment: I would generally agree with your asumption about memory useage being more or less equal. Both compile into a intermediate language (Bytecode/MSIL) that is then executed by a runtime. Both use a Garbage Collector. Wich is also the big question: Do you want memory footprint after forced GC runs? Would that even be a meaningfull measurement, given that the GC normally only runs when it absolutey has to?

Comment: I think it depends what do you want to test. Including frameworks like Spring of ASP.NET you will actually test frameworks, not the language itself. Otherwise, create a huge amount of similar objects and probably do some calculation upon them. Would be interesting to see actually

Comment: You can read this [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/92812/Benchmark-start-up-and-system-performance-for-Net)

Comment: Hi @Christopher, thanks, and good questions. I thought about creating a simple application which just allocates a few million objects, and measure the memory usage of that. I'm not sure if running/forcing the GC really is useful. I might show the efficiency of the runtime of how fast is clears memory, but I'm not sure if it demonstrates the efficiency between the two.

Comment: @OlegI I think so too. But I was considering a more realistic use case, like having a REST API running in a container. Maybe a hello world, or maybe something more.

Comment: @ErikPragt: When the objects  are allocated in memory, the only memory footprint are the actually data (wich might depending on avalible data structures/types), with some GC related overhead. I am unsure if Java Supports something like `lock` so that support might add some more memory overhead on the .NET side. Asuming of coruse the whole thing is not just optimized away by the JiT because nothing in the code **uses** a lock statement. Overall it sounds like it most parts of the Speed Rant/do not optimize prematurely would apply: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Answer (score 1):

For windows, there's a tool called [VMMap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/vmmap). It's pretty low level memory analysis utility. It's possible to attach this to any running process, so you could analyse both .NET app and Java app with this.

This is one of the tools proposed in the new [Konrad Kokosa book](https://prodotnetmemory.com/), too.

On the other hand, Linux platform is not so straight forward.

I hope that's all you need for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks for that, that's very helpful. I'll write simple program in Java and C#, run it on Mac, Linux and Windows, and I'll share the results on it. A tool like VMMap looks very useful, but maybe it would be good to also have a bit of view inside the runtimes, like the VM/CLR. Thanks for sharing, appreciate that!

Comment: @ErikPragt Glad to help!